# How to hijack AngularJS data binding process?

Tags: angularjs

`{{SomeData}}` means a data binding with a model in AngularJS.

Does this data binding process happen instantaneously?

In my case, I want to know the exact time when the new data is presented to the user.

So, are there any methods that I can insert some code before or after the data is presented that gets the time?

Comment: Have you read the entirety of the docs, this is an interesting question.. but I feel the answer is no.

Comment: @CallumLinington I am still new to angular. I have read some related docs but not find a appropriate approach yet.

Answer (score 2):

Probably no event that specifies what you asked for - but would a

```
$scope.$watch('SomeData', function(newVal, oldVal){
// code here
});
```

do the trick?

**Possible performance fix:**

If you take the var handling out of Angular (by triggering the change with a non-angular event like jQuery)  - you can then choose when to do $scope.$apply() - thereby controlling the timing of things without using a $watch.

Comment: All I would say is the more watchers that are created the more of a performance penalty you'll get, but then that's entirely down to the scenario in which this is used.

Comment: It does. But I prefer a more light-weight way to do this stuff because I want to get the real performance data...

Comment: I added an idea for a possible performance hack that would force your var change out of Angular and require  you to run $apply when you're ready.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can serve your purpose if you do it like in this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LBUiQaG8cAWAGDfzFro4?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = function() {
    var date = new Date();
    console.log("called just now at ", date)
    return 'World';
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name()}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```